# Mi programa me devuelve NaN como respuesta en c++

Tags: c++

Pues lo del titulo, soy relativamente nuevo en c++. La idea es usar el teorema de Taylor para calcular el valor del arcsin de x con poca precisión por eso el sumatorio solo te itera 7 veces
Llevo un rato buscando info y nada.

Ademas de que no que tipo de variable sea la más indicada para esto, si double o float, a mi me parece indiferente.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void leerdatos(double& x){
    do{
        cout << "indique un valor para x que este entre 0 y 1: ";
        cin >> x;
    }while((x<0) || (x>1));

}

double potencia(float base,int exponente){
    double potencia=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=exponente;i++){
        potencia=potencia*base;
    }
    return potencia;
}
double arriba(float x, int i){
    double arriba;
    for(int j; j<=i;j++){
        if(j>=3){
            arriba=arriba*((j*2)-3);
        }
    }
    return arriba*potencia(x,i*2-1);
}
double abajo(int i){
    double abajo;
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
        abajo=abajo*j*(i-1);
    }
    abajo=abajo*(2*(i-1)+1);
    return abajo;
}
double sumatorio(double x){
    double sumatorio;
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++){


        sumatorio+=arriba(x,i)/abajo(i);
    }
    return sumatorio;
}

int main(){
    double x;
    leerdatos(x);

    cout << endl << sumatorio(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias variables sin inicializar. Así que obtendrás resultados inconsistentes.

`arriba`, `abajo` y `sumatorio` tienen valores basura si no les das uno.

Desconozco qué valores deberías utilizar, pero intuyo que 0 en el sumatorio y 1 en los otros dos.

Normalmente obtienes `NaN` cuando divides 0 por 0, si haces operaciones con infinito o `NaN`. Puedes consultar algunos de los casos en la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).